# Quantum field theory at finite temperature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, causality, thermal-field-theory

Is there any notion of causality in Quantum field theory at finite temperature?

Comment: Is that not just the premise of regular qft?

Comment: Time coordinate is periodic in thermal field theory. So I assume regular notion of light cone doesn't apply hence the question.